# For $X,Y,Z\sim Bernoulli(1/2)$ s.t. $\forall A,B\in\{X,Y,Z\} P(A|B)=\alpha\in [0,1]$, what is the minimal possible $P(A|B,C)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to figure out what is the minimal possible entropy of 3 random variables that distribute as $Bernoulli(\frac{1}{2})$, and wer're given that $H(X|Y)=H(X|Z)=H(Y|X)=H(Y|Z)=H(Z|X)=H(Z|Y)=\beta\in[0,1]$.

I reduced it to the problem of finding three random variables  s.t. 
$\forall A,B\in\{X,Y,Z\}\quad P(A=1|B=1)=P(A=0|B=0)=\alpha\quad
\\
P(A=1|B=0)=P(A=0|B=1)=1-\alpha$
and s.t.
$P(A=a|B=b,C=c)$
gets a minimal/maximal value (meaning, as far from $\frac{1}{2}$ as possible. E.g. if they we're completely dependent, the conditioned probability would be either $0$ or $1$). I tend to believe that it's impossible for an arbitrary $\alpha$ to have the variables partially dependent pairwise, but completely dependent as a threesome. I tried to define such variables using another random variable $D=(d_1,d_2)\sim U([0,1]\times[0,1])$ and define in which part of the unit square each of $X,Y,Z$ gets the value $0$ or $1$, and found out that it possible to fill these constraints this way only with $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$ (which is equivalent to $\beta=0$).

However, I'm not sure how to prove it for every random variable, if it's indeed correct for general $X,Y,Z$ that follow the above constraints.

Comment: It would help to have a clarified statement of the problem.  If $X, Y, Z$ are iid Bernoulli 1/2, then you know the full probability distribution and there is nothing left to minimize. The use of $A, B$ is also confusing.  It sounds like you have $X, Y, Z$ iid and $H(X|Y)=H(Y|X)=H(X|Z)=H(Z|X)= ...= \beta$. Is that correct? (so you are just using $A,B$ as placeholders for all possible 6 combinations?) But for iid we have $H(X|Y)=H(X)=1$ (so why the use of $\beta \in [0,1]$?).  It is also not clear what the goal is, do you want to minimize $H(X,Y,Z)$?

Comment: Oh my, I used the wrong term, they aren't independent! Thanks, I'll fix it now.

Comment: It sounds like $X, Y, Z$ are Bernoullli 1/2, but not necessarily independent, and you want to minimize $H(X,Y,Z)$ subject to $H(X|Y)=...= \beta$.  I think the simplest way is to use the chain rule of entropy.  Is that how you are doing it?  Also, do you know how to solve it for the case $\beta=0$?  Or $\beta=1$?  I think the general case will be similar to the $\beta=1$ case.

Comment: Indeed! This is the original  question. I thought I reduced it to a simpler one. I solved it for $\beta=0$, and used the chain rule: $H(X,Y,Z)=H(X\vert Y,Z)+H(Y,Z) \geq H(Y,Z) = H(Y\vert Z)+H(Z)=\beta+1$.
For $\beta=0$ I managed to show that this is a tight bound. However, I'm not sure how to deal with $H(X\vert Y,Z)$ in the general case, these are the best boundaries I manage to find: $1+\beta=1+H(X\vert Z)+H(Z)\leq H(X,Y\vert Z)+H(Z)\leq H(X\vert Z)+H(Y\vert Z)+H(Z)=2\beta+1$
meaning: $1+\beta\leq H(X,Y,Z)\leq 1+2\beta$

Comment: We get $H(X,Y,Z) = H(X) + H(Y|X) + H(Z|X,Y) = 1  +\beta + H(Z|X,Y)$.  So we get the lower bound $1+\beta$ whenever we can achieve the constraints with $Z$ a perfect function of $X,Y$.  You did that for $\beta=0$, and you can also do it for $\beta=1$.  I thought we could do it for general $\beta$ but now I think that case may be more difficult. What is the context of this problem?

Comment: I'm taking a course in information theory, so this is a standalone question.
My approach above (in the original question) was to try and find such a $Z$ that achieves the constraints, but after applying the constraints, I found that the only valid parameter is $\beta=0$. However, it could likely be that I took a wrong direction, trying to use a uniform distribution to define $X,Y,Z$ upon.
Could you please give a hint how to build (or proof existence) of such $Z$ for $\beta=1$?

Comment: For the case $\beta=1$, there are standard examples where $X, Y, Z$ are pairwise independent Bernoulli $1/2$ (for each pair), but not mutually independent.

Comment: I tried to search for a general $\beta$, for $\beta=1$ I found now indeed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Minor observation: The constraints $P[X=0]=P[Y=0]=P[Z=0]=1/2$ imply $H(X)=H(Y)=H(Z)=1$ and $H(X|Y)=H(Y|X)$, $H(X|Z)=H(Z|X)$, $H(Y|Z)=H(Z|Y)$.